# Google Maps Geo giving JSONP error Unexpected token : or invalid label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

We're trying to get information of a user based on the lat longitude.

Our code has been working fine until a couple weeks ago when we started getting this error.

Here is our code:

```
var reverse_geo_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=[key]&sensor=false"
console.log("Calling " + reverse_geo_url);
new $.ajax(reverse_geo_url, {
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data) {
         // yay
    }
});
```

Problem is that we all of a sudden are getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Here is an example response from Google's servers (when I go directly to the url)

```
{
  "name": "33.0024912,-88.4218782",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "Paulette Rd, Macon, MS 39341, USA",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 6,
   "Country" : {
      "AdministrativeArea" : {
         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "MS",
         "Locality" : {
            "LocalityName" : "Macon",
            "PostalCode" : {
               "PostalCodeNumber" : "39341"
            },
            "Thoroughfare" : {
               "ThoroughfareName" : "Paulette Rd"
            }
         }
      },
      "CountryName" : "USA",
      "CountryNameCode" : "US"
   }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 32.9994289,
        "south": 32.9891822,
        "east": -88.4094885,
        "west": -88.4393238
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ -88.4238788, 32.9952338, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResponses

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps
>   API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you
>   need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the
>   request. This callback method processes the result(s). Note that the
>   geocoder may return more than one result.

According to the documentation callback is supposed to be supported. JQuery adds that callback header so I don't get why Google isn't honoring it.

*Edit: For reference, the url that my app tries to call is http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=33.8024912,-84.4218782&key=[my key here]&sensor=false&callback=jQuery16409036452900618315_1335293866369&_=1335293866469
Is this something on Google's side? Or is something on our side? Again, this code used to work perfectly.

Other posts that I've seen on StackOverFlow, people are saying that when this error shows up in means that the server doesn't support JSONP... What's confusing to me is that this used to work... Did google change their API?

Comment: what is the URL ajax is calling after jQuery parsed it?

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=33.8024912,-84.4218782&key=[my key here]&sensor=false&callback=jQuery16409036452900618315_1335293866369&_=1335293866469

Comment: Have you checked your usage quota and billing info? There's a note in the docs: "* Note: The Maps API usage limits will be enforced from early 2012. ..."

Comment: @Christian don't know where i would find that... and i'm almost certain we haven't hit their limit... especially because we still do get responses back... and if i remove the key it still gives same result

Comment: You can check this in https://code.google.com/apis/console. You're using the Google Maps API V2, which is officially deprecated, although it should continue to work. I don't think this could be the reason based on what you stated and seeing that their Courtesy limit is 25,000 queries/day. Sorry for the misleading info

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why are you doing ajax calls to do geocoding? You could be using the Google Maps API directly and more simply: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: Doesn't the client have to download parts of the geocoder to access the Google Geocoding API? Maybe overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the docs it seems you don't need to register any more to use this api,

I used this successfully :

```
var url = string.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q={0}&output=xml", encodedPostCode);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: .Format()? are you sure it's javascript?

Comment: @Ivan the main point was that there was no need to register, obviously his code is C# but is calling into js but 'without' any auth parameters, point was clear to me.